# Error when trying to use aws cli and buckets with periods

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm using the aws cli (`aws-cli/1.3.23 Python/2.7.5 Darwin/13.2.0`) to access my s3 buckets and it is failing with the following error if the bucket name as a period in it.

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://my.bucket
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3-us-east-1a.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /my.bucket?delimiter=/&prefix= (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

Everything works fine if the bucket doesn't have periods:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://mybucket
```

According to aws docs, periods are fine and I have no issues access the buckets via the website.

Comment: Where is the documentation you state that says periods are valid?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but I just tried to duplicate this problem and I had no issues doing an ls or otherwise operating on a bucket with a period.  The CLI version reports as:  aws-cli/1.3.21 Python/2.6.9 Linux/3.10.42-52.145.amzn1.x86_64.  Installed boto packages are python-boto-2.30.0-1.0.amzn1.noarch and python-botocore-0.55.0-1.1.amzn1.noarch I'm running on Amazon Linux and did a yum update before and after doing this test.

Comment: I'm running this from OS X. I've downloaded aws cli from the aws site and it seems to come with `botocore-0.57.0`. How do I tell what version of boto I'm running? How do I upgrade it? I'm also use google's gsutil and it also seems to use boto, so maybe there is a conflict? Is there a better place to get the aws cli?

Comment: Update: I installed pip and install boto, then reinstalled the aws-cli and still get the same issue.

Comment: Is the location for the bucket and the S3 API endpoint you are using in the same region?

Answer (score 4):

Had this same problem today. The solution is specifying your region.

What wasn't working:

```
aws s3 sync --acl public-read dist/ s3://some.bucket.name/
```

What works now:

```
aws s3 --region us-east-1 sync --acl public-read dist/ s3://some.bucket.name/
```

EDIT:
If all your buckets are going to exist in the same regions, go to command line (in OSX):

```
aws configure
```

If you haven't supplied your AWS keys, do so then. Question #3 should be Default region. in my case I entered:

```
us-east-1
```

Now I no longer have to specify region unless the bucket is outside my default region.

Comment: If you use Ireland as region you need to set this to eu-west-1 (and not ireland even though that is what the bucket say it's region is)

Answer (score 2):

...I encountered a similar problem with my account.

I found (through trial and error) that when I used the wrong region identifier, I was getting the Errno 8.

Here's what worked:

- us-west-2

Here's what didn't work:

- us-west
- us-west-2a

I couldn't find any definitive help about what would work (or not work) when specifying a region identifier, so this answer is completely empirical and may not help in all cases.